# How to make treeview with load data on demand?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

How to make tree with loading data on demand? I've backend which method that returns for me root level nodes and other method that returns me children of parent by parents id. I want to build tree where I click on the node and tree load data and draw for me new branch with children and so on. I don't know how deepth this tree will be. How to implement it with mat-tree? I tried recursive function *ngFor but it doesnt work with mat-tree. I want something like this [link](https://www.lidorsystems.com/support/articles/angular/treeview/treeview-load-on-demand/) but without any external libraries

Comment: the first example of mat-tree https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples show what you are looking for

Comment: @Eliseo it's not a good example because datamap is defined and I don't know how deepth my structure will be. I have many arrays inside other arrays.

Comment: It's a example, just change the "DynamicDatabase" for your "ServiceDataBase". Just replace the functions initialData,getChildren and isExpandable to get the data from a httpClient.get(....) or similar

Comment: @Eliseo Have you any example how to do it? I think isExpandable won't work for my example because I don't know about children. I want load children and their children by click on parent.

Comment: I put in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5or22?file=app%2Ftree-dynamic-example.ts and example, take a llok to the dataService. I used "of" and delay to simulate a real call. If I have some time, try to explain the changes

Comment: I improve the code in the stackblitz to avoid an unnecesary search when you toggle to false a node, and add a briefly explain

Comment: @Eliseo I added custom add new node, edit node. Have you any idea how to refresh tree without click on arrow?

Comment: I updated my answer, I hope this can help you. Remember that, you need update the database and change the math-tree. It's very similar to when in Angular we has a master-detail page and change one element. After change the database, we can refresh the list or change the list programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I create a service with two functions

```
getRootNodes(){}
```

and

```
getChildren(node:any){}
```

getRootNodes, return the first level of root.

getChildren(nodes:any), return the "children". But, not only return an array of strings, I make this return an array of object with a propertie "isExpandable". For material-tree is necesary know when a children has children

The next change is usign our service in the DinamicDataSource. Our toggleNode must use of the service. if !expands is the code that was under the setTimeOut, Well, we don't need a setTimeOut, of course.

If expand=true, we call to the service and subscribe to the data. INTO the subscribe the code under the setTimeOut.

See that in both case we need call to this.dataChange.next(this.data)

```
toggleNode(node: DynamicFlatNode, expand: boolean) {
    const index = this.data.indexOf(node);
    if (!expand)
    {
      let count = 0;
        for (let i = index + 1; i < this.data.length
          && this.data[i].level > node.level; i++, count++) {}
        this.data.splice(index + 1, count);
        this.dataChange.next(this.data);
    }
    else
    {
    node.isLoading = true;
    this.dataService.getChildren(node.item).subscribe(children=>{
      if (!children || index < 0) { // If no children, or cannot find the node, no op
        node.isLoading = false;

        return;
      }
      if (expand) {
        const nodes = children.map(obj =>
          new DynamicFlatNode(obj.name, node.level + 1, obj.isExpandable));
        this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...nodes);
      }
      node.isLoading = false;
      // notify the change
      this.dataChange.next(this.data);

    })
    }
  }
```

The last change is pass to a ngOnInit the functions of the constructor in the TreeDynamicExample

```
ngOnInit()
  {
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<DynamicFlatNode>(this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new DynamicDataSource(this.treeControl, this.dataService);
    this.dataService.getRootNodes().subscribe(res=>{
      this.dataSource.data = res.map(name => new DynamicFlatNode(name, 0, true));
    })
  }
```

See that, before equal this.dataSourceData to a DynamicFlatNode, we need get the data and make it in the subscribe

**Update**: Demystifying the DinamicData Source.

Well, to understand the tree-dinamic we can take a look at what is "data" in DynamicData Source. This data it's only an array of object with the properties:     item,level,expandable and loading. So, it's look like

```
[
{item: "Fruits",level:0,expandable:true,isLoading:false},
{item: "Apple",level:1,expandable:true,isLoading:false},
{item: "Orange",level:1,expandable:false,isLoading:false},
{item: "Bannana",level:1,expandable:false,isLoading:false},
{item: "Vegetables",level:0,expandable:true,isLoading:false}
]
```

Yes, it's just a simple array. But it's an array ordered. So we can create a function addNode in our DinamicDataSource, like

```
  addSubNode(index:number,name:string,isExpandable:boolean)
  {
     const node=this.data[index];
     const dfn={item: name,
         level:node.level+1,
         expandable:isExpandable,
         isLoading:false}
     this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...[dfn]);
     this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }

  addNode(index:number,name:string,isExpandable:boolean)
  {
     const node=this.data[index];
     const dfn={item: name,
         level:node.level,
         expandable:isExpandable,
         isLoading:false}
     this.data.splice(index + 1, 0, ...[dfn]);
     this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }

  changeNode(index:number,name:string)
  {
     this.data[index].item=name;
  }
```

See that, after change the array -adding a node/subnode we need call to this.dataChange.next(this.data), because a splice change the "content" of the array, but not the array itselft. We can also do some "bizarro" as

```
 this.data=[...this.data]
```

but the guys of Angular Material make us our live easy and we can use .next (It's the reason because data really ist not an array else the value of a BehaviorSubject)

I hope this aclaration remove the "magic" of the dinamic-tree. I [forked the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5or22-zlmkuh?file=app/tree-dynamic-example.ts) to add tree simple buttons to add a node, add a subnode and change the node

Comment: Nice stackblitz demo